# Car audio system showing shorter duration for mp3 files after ffmpeg processing

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I have about 1200 mp3 files (about 45 minutes each) that contain lectures (not music) I used some ffmpeg commands to speed them up by 1.5x and to convert them to Mono instead of Sterio (to reduce file size to fit in a cd).

I used these two commands (in two stages):

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=1.5,volume=1.2" -q:a 100 first_stage.mp3

ffmpeg -i first_stage.mp3 -ac 1 -b:a 32k final.mp3
```

After I performed this in batch, when I put them in my car mp3 player, I noticed that all the files *show* maximum of 7 minutes duration, but they play all the file with no problem. My car mp3 player shows a countdown , and I used to look for the remaining time of each file to know whether I start a new one or not, etc.

Now, all the files start with 5 to 7 minutes (instead of 30-45 minutes), and it counts down to zero and remains 0 to the end of the file, so I complete the lecture blindly with no timer, which is annoying for me.

What can I do to fix this, i.e., to let the car player read the time correctly?

Comment: Does it happen in other players? Are the files CBR or VBR?

Comment: I tested them on my pc (MediaPlayerClassic), no problem. I have not tested in other car players. 
What are CBR and VBR?

Comment: I 've googled CBR and VBR, I think they are CBR, but I am not sure.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/607703/wrong-audio-duration-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @golimar Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it after I finish my work, then I will tell you whether it works or not.

Comment: @golimar As reported in the link you mentioned, they suggest the following command `ffmpeg -f in.mp3 -i -write_xing 0 out.mp3` I tried it it gave me an error! `Unknown input format "in.mp3"`

Comment: Your options are incorrect: `ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -write_xing 0 out.mp3`

Comment: Thank you very much @golimar, the `-write_xing 0` solved it. I will add an answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard what options are incorrect?

Comment: @MohammadElNesr You don't need `-f`. The file name was in the incorrect location: needs to go after `-i`. See my previous comment and compare it to your command in preceding comment.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard You are right, I removed it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @golimar, I found the solution

One should add the parameter `-write_xing 0` before the output file name.

The conversion (in one line) should be like that:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=1.5,volume=1.2" -q:a 100  -ac 1 -b:a 32k -write_xing 0 out.mp3
```